# How to get text content of one h3 at a time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty to get text content of h1 at a time when I click on any button element . Can anyone help me out please?

```
    <div id="makeSelection" ><h1>Text Content 1</h1>
    <button onclick="eveent()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="makeSelection" ><h1>Text Content 2</h1>
        <button onclick="eveent()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="makeSelection" ><h1>Text Content 3</h1>
        <button onclick="eveent()">Click Me</button>
    </div>


     function eveent(){

        var text = document.getElementById('makeSelection').textContent;

        console.log(text);



                    }
```

Comment: Well you loop through all of them, hence you get all.

Comment: @Lain: `this.textContent` won't work since the function is called in a way that lets `this` refer to the element.

Comment: Change your inline event handler to `eveent(this)` and define the function as `function eveent(element) { console.log(element.textContent); }`.

Comment: @FelixKling I have just edited my question. Can u please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in javascript and clear the click event from `HTML` template..

Then use `eveent.bind(this, item.textContent)` to bind the particular item which was listened in click event.

**Edit:**

If you want to add event listener to a button, then get the button like, (Assuming you have class name for each div as `makeSelection` and not same `id's` repeated.

```
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".makeSelection button");
```

Then make an event listener like,

```
item.addEventListener('click', eveent.bind(this,item.previousElementSibling.textContent))
```

Through `item.previousElementSibling.textContent` , we are passing the textContent of `h1` tag..

```js
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".makeSelection button");

function eveent(clickedItem){
  console.log(clickedItem)
}

selection.forEach((item,i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', eveent.bind(this,item.previousElementSibling.textContent))
})
```

```html
<div class="makeSelection" >
  <h1>Text Content 1</h1>
   <button>Click Me</button>
 </div>
 <div class="makeSelection">
   <h1>Text Content 2</h1>
   <button>Click Me</button>
 </div>
 <div class="makeSelection">
   <h1>Text Content 3</h1>
   <button>Click Me</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can u please answer according to my question that I edited few mins before? Many thanks..

Comment: @David, Answer updated.. Please make sure you are using unique ```id's```.. Otherwise use class if you have same name..

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how you could do it:

- Give ID-s to the headings.
- Call the click event with the id of the desired heading.
- Do your thing with the element content. (In this example, you console log it's text content)

```js
function clickEvent (target){
  var heading = document.querySelector(target);
  if (heading) {
    console.log(heading.textContent);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="heading-1">Text Content 1</h1>
  <button onclick="clickEvent('#heading-1')">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="heading-2">Text Content 2</h1>
  <button onclick="clickEvent('#heading-2')">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="heading-3">Text Content 3</h1>
  <button onclick="clickEvent('#heading-3')">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** I removed the duplicate ids from the divs, as they are not required and also duplicate IDs are not valid in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example with plain Javascript to read the content of clicked div

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <script>
            function eveent(c) {
                alert(c.childNodes[0].innerText);
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <div class="makeSelection" onclick="eveent(this)"><h1>Text Content 1</h1></div>
         <div class="makeSelection" onclick="eveent(this)"><h1>Text Content 2</h1></div>
         <div class="makeSelection" onclick="eveent(this)"><h1>Text Content 3</h1></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get the h1 inside "makeSelection" and make button outs

```
<div id="makeSelection"><h1>Text Content 1
  </h1>
function eveent(){

        var text = document.querySelector("#makeSelection h1").innerText 
}
```